# Randomly read text from specific column in a file using Java

Tags: java

I would like to randomly select single name from column1 between Robert,Shawn,John.

Example The File has following names

```
Robert,Brian

Shawn,Bay

John,Paul
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated

```
    FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+path);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objfile ));
    String line = in.readLine();
    while (line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        String eachRecord[]=line.trim().split(",");
        Random rand = new Random();
//trying to randomly select text from specific row in a property file

    sendKeys(firstName,rand.nextInt((eachRecord[0]));
    line = in.readLine();       

    }

}
```

Comment: how do you expect `eachRecord[0]` to be an integer ?

Comment: You need to define what  'randomly select text from specific row' means. What kind of output do you expect for what kind of input?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to randomly select the names from the first column such as 
Column1 
Robert
Shawn
John

Comment: Please edit your question and show some example input (a few lines is sufficient), and an example of the output you desire from that input.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(path_of_your_file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String sCurrentLine;
ArrayList<String> nameList=new ArrayList<String>(); //keep each first column entry inside this list.
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(sCurrentLine, ",");
    String name=st.nextToken();
    nameList.add(name);
}

System.out.println(nameList.get((int)(Math.random()*nameList.size())));

//close file resources at finally block.
```

Comment: That won’t compile.  You probably meant `random.nextInt(eachRecord.length)` … but even that probably isn’t answering the (currently unclear) question, which aims to “randomly select the names from the first column.”

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This gets a random name from column 1 into the variable `randomName`:

```
    final int column = 1;
    final String path = "file.ext";
    Random rand = new Random();
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String randomName = lines.get(rand.nextInt(lines.size())).split(",")[column - 1];
```